# Call a C# method in time interval from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I'm calling a C# method from javascript which will returns a Json string. and I'm writing the JSON values in text boxes. C# method converts data table to JSON. So far it's working correctly.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
   //returns "[{\"TAG1\":100,\"TAG2\":100}]" from method 
   var data = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString()%>'); 
   $('#TextBox1').val(data[0].TAG1);
   $('#TextBox2').val(data[0].TAG2);
   }
    </script>
```

code behind

```
public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCon"].ConnectionString;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
          @"SELECT TOP 1 
                   DATATIME, 
                   TAG1,
                   TAG2 
              FROM DATATABLE1  
          ORDER BY 1 DESC", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = 
              new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to update text box value in particular time interval(my case 3sec) for getting latest datatable values in textboxes
So tried setInterval function. but it doesn't update the latest value.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function initialize() {
            //returns "[{\"TAG1\":100,\"TAG2\":100}]"     
            var data = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
            $('#TextBox1').val(data[0].TAG1);
            $('#TextBox2').val(data[0].TAG2);
        },1000);
    </script>
```

Is there any solution for this problem? Is that advisable to call a method from java script every 3 sec? or any other way to get the latest data table value in text box?

Comment: *"I'm calling a C# method from javascript."* No, you aren't. You're running a C# method **on the server** when the page is requested, and then later, once the page text (with the output of that method embedded in it) goes to the client, the browser runs the JavaScript code which reads the text embedded in the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You got the problem. what is the possible solution to get it done?

Comment: Create an endpoint and call the method with ajax, then set the values again.

Other possible solution, which I honestly do not recommend, but I assume you are using WebForms, is to set an update panel and a timer on it to refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WebService (.asmx) to your Project.

Then add your method as a WebMethod to the service:

```
namespace YourName.Space
{
 //Here is some auto-generated stuff like [WebService(Namespace = "http//tempuri.org")]
 public class MyWebsevice : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {
  [WebMethod]
  public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
  {
   // your stuff
  }
 }
}
```

Register the Webservice on your Page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
 <Services>
  <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MyWebsevice.asmx" />
 </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Call it from JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(LoadMyData, 3000);
    });

    function LoadMyData() {
     YourName.Space.MyWebsevice.ConvertDataTabletoString(onSuccess, onFailure)
    }

    function onSuccess(result) {
     var data = JSON.parse(result);
     $('#TextBox1').val(data[0].TAG1);
     $('#TextBox2').val(data[0].TAG2);
    }

    function onFailure(result, userContext, methodName) {
     // do something if necessary.
    }
</script>
```

I hope it helps.

**Edit**: Instead of the "$(document).ready()" use OnLoad="myOnLoadFunction()"

```
var var1;
function myOnLoadFunction(){
 var1= setInterval(LoadMyData, 3000);
}
```

call `<body onload="myOnLoadFunction()">`

Comment: Values doesn't pass to textboxes. It shows empty values., need to change anything?

Comment: Have you debugged the service and the JS?

Comment: Web service returns correct json value. But JS doesn't received it

Comment: Does it enter onSuccess or onFailure? what is the value of result?

Comment: LoadMyData function isn't triggered.., If it is possible you can look at my code..

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/psrm6h .asmx code. aspx code https://jsfiddle.net/8chcdecg/

Comment: you musst uncomment the line: //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: problem remains same, LoadMyData() not triggered, is this line correct `Loaddata.MyWebsevice.ConvertDataTabletoString(onSuccess, onFailure)`  ? and I added web service in my website project. haven't created a new project for webservice, as well is webservice path is correct?

Comment: You need to call "Namespace.ClassName.MethodName" in your case: "Loaddata.WebService.ConvertDataTabletoString" your class in fiddle is "WebService" not "MyWebsevice"

Comment: Yes, I changed. and added webservice handler in web confiq. good news is it's working when pass function in `onload="LoadMyData()"` now only problem is set interval.. hopefully we almost reached

Comment: problem remains same LoadMyData function not triggered. we're missing some thing in set interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105911/discussion-between-rj10-and-daniel-pl).